# What is the likelihood function for nominal logistic regression as per Dobson pg 181

Tags: statistics, logistic-regression

On pg. 181 of Dobson, Intro to GLM, https://ocd.lcwu.edu.pk/cfiles/Statistics/EC/Stat-402/AnIntroductiontoGeneralizedLinearModelsbyAnnetteJ.DobsonAdrianGBarnettz-lib.org.pdf
nominal logistic regression is described, quoting the text

```
 logit(pij) = log(pij/pi1) = ....
```

But, I thought logit(pij) = log(pij/(1-pij))   note: I'm a novice

Question #1 - doesn't that seem a little peculiar?

Also, no likelihood or loglikelihood function in terms of pij/pi1 is given.

Question #2 - what is the likelihood function in terms of pij/pi1 for j = 1...J-1

Question #3 - loglikelihood, score functions, and info matrix?

Question #4 - is there are readable reference for this material?